# Laravel - Weird behaviour with query

Tags: php, laravel

So, I'm using a simple method to display an edit form, using information I've seen from various Laravel CRUD tutorials.

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $users
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(User $user)
{
    //Get user with specified username
    $user = User::findOrFail($user)->get();

    return view('users.edit', compact('user')); //pass user and roles data to view

}
```

As you can see, this method couldn't be any simpler.

The route for this method is as follows:

`/user/{user}/edit`

Where `{user}` is the Primary Key of the model bound to the route, in my case this happens to be `$username`.

So, If I were to enter `/user/stevew/edit` I'd expect the query to be the following:

`select * from`users`where username = ? and`users`.`deleted_at`is null limit 1`

- ? = stevew

The thing is: the query isn't returning the user I expect, instead of returning the details for stevew, I get the details for another user: edwardl.

This is the User table migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('displayName');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('role')->nullable();
    $table->string('department')->nullable();
    $table->string('location')->nullable();
    $table->string('directDialIn')->nullable();
    $table->string('mobileNumber')->nullable();
    $table->string('managedByUsername')->nullable();
    $table->string('managedByDisplayName')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

This is a dump of the queries executed

```
QueryExecuted {#736 ▼
  +sql: "select * from `users` where `username` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1"
  +bindings: array:1 [▼
    0 => "jesseo"
  ]
  +time: 6.25
  +connection: MySqlConnection {#306 ▶}
  +connectionName: "mysql"
}
QueryExecuted {#7458 ▼
  +sql: "select * from `users` where `username` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1"
  +bindings: array:1 [▼
    0 => "stevew"
  ]
  +time: 0.62
  +connection: MySqlConnection {#306 ▶}
  +connectionName: "mysql"
}
QueryExecuted {#14214 ▼
  +sql: "select `roles`.*, `model_has_roles`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `model_has_roles`.`model_type` as `pivot_model_type` from `roles` inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `model_has_roles`.`model_id` = ? and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = ? ◀"
  +bindings: array:2 [▼
    0 => "jesseo"
    1 => "App\User"
  ]
  +time: 0.84
  +connection: MySqlConnection {#306 ▶}
  +connectionName: "mysql"
}
QueryExecuted {#21003 ▼
  +sql: "select * from `users` where `users`.`username` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null"
  +bindings: array:14 [▼
    0 => 102
    1 => "stevew"
    2 => "Steve Williams"
    3 => "Steve.Williams@newable.co.uk"
    4 => "Web Manager, Digital"
    5 => "Digital"
    6 => "Head Office"
    7 => "+44 (0)20 7940 1598 "
    8 => ""
    9 => "elouttit"
    10 => "Edward Louttit"
    11 => null
    12 => null
    13 => null
  ]
  +time: 0.76
  +connection: MySqlConnection {#306 ▶}
  +connectionName: "mysql"
}
```

I get that the first query is the logged in user, which makes sense, the second query is the query I expect to run, it even has the correct username.

I just can't see where it is getting a different username value.

Comment: It's probably converting the string to an integer, which makes for funky comparisons. `find()`/`findOrFail()` automatically checks for the id (primary key), not the username.

Comment: `->get()` returns a `Collection`, so you'll get an array-like object of a single `User`. Either use `->firstOrFail()`, or use `->where(...)->first()`, which will be `null` or a single `User`.

Comment: FYI `public function edit(User $user)` ... that typehint appears wrong ... the passed argument should be the matched `string` from your route unless I'm totally missing something :p

Comment: I thought it was? :/

Comment: When you typehint User, laravels di container will try to resolve this dependency and pass a new instance of your user model to the controller ... so no matter what URL you call `/user/bob/edit`,  `/user/john/edit/` etc you will always receive the same result set from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its going to be a bit messy in the comments, here is what I meant by

> When you typehint User, laravels di container will try to resolve this dependency and pass a new instance of your user model to the controller

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    print_r($user);
    // output is a new instance of an eloquent model
}
```

But what you most likely want is the user name from the URL

```
public function edit(string $user)
{
    print_r($user);
    // output is the string from your route e.g. /user/Bob/edit -> output Bob
}
```

Just give both a try and you will notice the difference =)

btw. as mentioned, you'll still need to change the query to e.g.

```
User::where('username', $user)->first();
```

btw. personally I sometimes like to be more explicit with parameters to avoid confusion. e.g. `/user/{username}/edit` and the controller method `edit($username)`. Then you'll be more like ... "oh yeah .. its the username, not the entire user object" =)

Comment: I know this probably sounds stupid, but how is that different?

Comment: Oh... I've just got it.

Comment: glad you got it =) I really wouldnt have known how to explain it otherwise =)

Comment: I forgot that if you bind a model to a route you don't have to search for it again... :/ As the model is already bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get user with specified username
$user = User::findOrFail($user)->get();
```

In laravel find / findOrFail refers to the primary id of the table

what you should use if its other than the id

```
$user = User::where('username', $user)->first();
```

This way you'll be getting the right user

Comment: I'd suggest `first()` or `firstOrFail()` instead of `get()`. Otherwise it's going to return a collection instead of a single user/null value.